# Need to send sms alerts for services monitored in xymon monitoring tool

Tags: sms, monitoring

I have a xymon server as a monitoring tool. I want to send sms alerts for any process check fails for eg: if disk utilisation is higher than 90% then it should send a alert in sms to the recipient .

I already have a sms gateway which can send sms alerts.But i need to integrate it with the xymon. To use sms gateway we can use something like:

```
curl http://url=sms&api_key=key&format=json&to=contact_numsender=sender_name&unicode=1 --data-urlencode message=msg_to_be_sent
```

so here in message i need to add the message which xymon detects as in color yellow or red and it should send sms after recovery of the alert as well.

Its working fine with the emails. And the server on which `xymon server` is installed is on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

To send SMS alerts with your Xymon server, you could use our program PageGate. PageGate allows you to send SMS by TAP, Internet (SMTP, WCTP and SNPP) and cellular hardware (cellular modems, routers and gateways) and can be easily integrated with Xymon Monitor with the following steps: 
https://www.notepage.net/xymon/how-to-integrate.htm

Our documentation can be found here:
https://www.notepage.net/manuals/pg/v8/server/html/index.html

The steps to install PageGate can be found in the 'Installation' section.

Information on how PageGate can be configured to deliver SMS can be found in the 'How PageGate Sends Messages' section.